# mutating method sent to immutable object' in nsmutablearray

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I want to remove objects from NSmutableArray can one tell me the Best way to remove from NSMutableArray

.h

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *arr_property;
```

.m

```
_arr_property=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
MTPop *lplv = [[MTPop alloc] initWithTitle:SelectProperty(APP_SHARE.language)
                                   options:[_arr_property valueForKeyPath:@"property_list.property_type_name"] 
                                   handler:^(NSInteger anIndex) {
    txt_Property.text=[[_arr_property valueForKeyPath:@"property_list.property_type_name"] objectAtIndex:anIndex];
    NSLog(@"index number %ld",(long)anIndex);
```

remove object--->>>

```
NSLog(@"index number %@",[_arr_property valueForKey:@"property_list"]);
[[_arr_property valueForKeyPath:@"property_list.property_type_name"] removeObjectAtIndex:anIndex];  ////hear the app is crashing
```

app is crashing error iam getting is

```
2015-06-09 13:21:31.104 Estater[2170:62264] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

Comment: Is that really all there is to your code? You make an _empty_ NSMutableArray and then try to call `valueForKeyPath:` on it? What sense does that make?

Comment: `[_arr_property valueForKeyPath:@"property_list.property_type_name"]` this is not mutable array, its `NSArray`, you need to convert your data completely to mutable.

Comment: thx @iphonic but its not working  i am totally confused with array's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about your code:

```
_arr_property=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

You now have an *empty* NSMutableArray. It has *no* elements.

```
[... removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

What did we just say? The array has *no* elements. It has *no* element 0 - to have an element 0 it would need to have *one* element at least, but it doesn't. There is nothing to remove.

```
[_arr_property valueForKeyPath:@"property_list.property_type_name"]
```

That part is the weirdest, but let's carry on. When called on an array, `valueForKeyPath:` results in an NSArray - not an NSMutableArray. So this gives you an *empty NSArray*. But you cannot say `removeObjectAtIndex:` to an NSArray, even if it empty - it is not mutable. That's the crash you are experiencing.

Comment: @thxq for ur valuable time @matt---> just look at this code ones                  MTPop *lplv = [[MTPop alloc] initWithTitle:SelectProperty(APP_SHARE.language) options:[_arr_property valueForKeyPath:@"property_list.property_type_name"] handler:^(NSInteger anIndex) {
 txt_Property.text=[[_arr_property valueForKeyPath:@"property_list.property_type_name"] objectAtIndex:anIndex ];
NSLog(@"index number %ld",(long)anIndex);
NSLog(@"index number %@",[_arr_property valueForKey:@"property_list"]);     
 [[_arr_property valueForKeyPath:@"property_list.property_type_name"] removeObjectAtIndex:anIndex];

Comment: That doesn't change my answer. Look at the last paragraph of my answer. `valueForKeyPath:` gives an NSArray, not an NSMutableArray. You cannot send `removeObjectAtIndex:` to it.

Comment: @matt do you know the meaning of that `valueForKeyPath:@"property_list.property_type_name"`? weird keypath.  Can i suppose that he extended the basic `NSMutableArray` with some category?

Answer (score 0):

The real error is that you are calling removeObject on an **element** of your NSMutableArray:

```
[-->[_arr_property valueForKeyPath:@"property_list.property_type_name"]<-- removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

The array looks empty, but if filled with something, to remove the first element you should do instead:

```
[_arr_property removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: [_arr_property removeObjectAtIndex:0]; //app is crashing :(

Comment: Then the array is simply empty, i would recommend to add the full error to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you cannot work with `NSMutableArray` for key value coding it does not support. You must better use `NSMutableDictionary` for it.
As dictionaries store objects based on a key, whereas arrays store objects based on an index.

You can use NSMutableDictionary like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[dict setObject:something forKey:@"Some Key"];

// ... and later ...

id something = [dict objectForKey:@"Some Key"];
```

Secondly, `valueForKeyPath:` returns a value not array and `valueForKey:` returns array of value for the key and also that array is not mutable.

**Edit:**

Thirdly, after researching more on `valueForKeyPath:`, [found its use in collection operation](http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/) and [syntax for using is](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html). So, do it by changing

```
[_arr_property valueForKeyPath:@"property_list.property_type_name"]
```

To

```
[_arr_property valueForKeyPath:@"@property_list.property_type_name"]
```

Comment: [_arr_property valueForKeyPath:@"property_list.property_type_name"]
To

[_arr_property valueForKeyPath:@"@property_list.property_type_name"]  didt get

Comment: it will not as the code provided is indicating you are trying to access an empty array which is just initialized before accessing it. @ShaikNayeemuddin